# Is it possible to modify a .js/.json file in a Document Library using only javascript ?

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint-2007, sharepointdocumentlibrary

We have a html file in a Document Library which contains a large html table with useful info. (this files is exported manually from a different app)
The info would be even more useful/accessible if it was in json format. (far faster to load and more accessible)
The use case would be :

- User uploads more recent file html file to the document library
- User
  goes to a wikipage on the sharepoint site and clicks on a large
  button "Update JSON"
- A javascript does the following

  - reads the
    contents of the html file
  - generates valid json
  - saves this json to an existing .json file in the document library, overwriting the current contents

Any ideas ??

Thanks / Colm

P.S. Everything has to be client-side, javascript is the only option.

Comment: What do you mean with "saves this json"? Do you know you can only save files in a client-side sandbox and only with the browsers supporting it?

Comment: The json is saved to an existing file in a Document library on the sharepoint server, not locally.

Comment: Ok, but you can't do this with Javascript alone. You need some server-side handler to perform that. So, back to the original question: what do you mean with "saves this json"? Should it send an AJAX request or what?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered some link for similar task, hopefully it would help you to some extent.

http://dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2013/02/using-jsom-to-write-small-files-to-a-sharepoint-2013-document-library/